# Retrieving several values from a xml node (xpath)

Tags: c#, asp.net, xpath

This is part of a xml document:

```
<directory level="Beginner">
    <cel row="0" column="0" visible="no">2</cel>
</directory>
```

How can i exactly put those 3 values in a string?

Every time my string returns null. Xpath xpression as following:

```
string xpath = "//directory[@level='" + directoryLevel+ "'] /cel[@row='" + amountOfRows + "' and @column='" + amountOfColumns+ "']";
```

The error has to be somewhere around the "and" (2nd attribute), because if i leave that part out the string is not null anymore.

How exactly can i get the value of column into my string and what causes this error?

Best Regards.

Comment: What exactly is your desired resulting string?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the "and" with "][" like so:

```
string xpath = "//directory[@level='" + directoryLevel+ "']/cel[@row='" + amountOfRows + "'][@column='" + amountOfColumns+ "']";
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be valid xpath so I am not sure what the problem is.  I tested around a little with the xml and static text and was able to build the following xpath statement which works fine:

```
//directory[@level='Beginner']/cel[(@row='0') and (@column='0')]
```

Could the problem be related to your variables and not xpath?  Are you absolutely sure "amountOfRows" and "amountOfColumns" have the values you expect?

Comment: Yes because the rows are in a for loop and so are the columns in a likewise manner. Beginner and 2 times 0 when i debug, yet the string says null.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is somewhere else. I wrote the following code:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml("<directory level=\"Beginner\"><cel row=\"0\" column=\"0\" visible=\"no\">2</cel></directory>");

string directoryLevel = "Beginner";
string amountOfRows = "0";
string amountOfColumns = "0";

string xpath = "//directory[@level='" + directoryLevel+ "']/cel[@row='" + amountOfRows + "' and @column='" + amountOfColumns+ "']";
XmlNode node = document.SelectSingleNode(xpath);

Console.WriteLine(node.OuterXml);
```

The output was:

```
<cel row="0" column="0" visible="no">2</cel>
```

Conclusion: the xpath expression works as expected.